What is a note article?
I submitted a paper to Classical and Quantum Gravity journal. One referee said it is good but the other one posed some questions. After answering, the referee has said:
Unfortunately, I will not be able to recommend this manuscript for publication.  However, I do still find the analysis of Section 3 interesting, so perhaps with some restructuring that section alone could be published as a note.
I do not understand his/her meaning by “publishing as a note”.
It is worth noting that I am a PhD student required of having a paper.
Moreover, the status of my manuscript is now “minor revisions required”!
Following is the editor’s note:
As an editor of CQG, I was asked to consider whether the author(s) have satisfactorily responded to the requested revisions by the referees. I do not believe that the authors have satisfactorily responded to Referee 1's concerns.

Wait, if the editor in charge says "Minor revisions", then it doesn't matter what the reviewer says! If you're confused, ask the editor!

Look at the Instructions for Authors for the journal. Many journals have different formats for different submissions. There is no standard, some will only have one type. I would expect something called a "Note" to be shorter in format than other publications in that journal.
Whether a "Note" counts as a "paper" for whatever requirements your institution has for PhD students is not any business of the journal. It's not their decision or responsibility at all, that's up to your institution and an issue you have to raise with them and them alone.
Your next steps will be to

Learn what a Note is; start at the journal website.

Once you know what a Note is, decide if you might want to go that route. This might include consulting with your institution to find out if this "counts" for you.

If your preference is not to publish as a note, you should try to better satisfy Reviewer 1 or ask the editor for clarification on what they think it would take to accept your manuscript, because it's a bit unclear if they are both giving you "minor revisions" which suggests minor changes that are easily addressed and also saying you have not responded sufficiently to Reviewer 1's concerns.

If you're fine publishing as a Note, you should ask the editor if they agree with the reviewer and would consider Section 3 as a Note.

If you can't get your full paper accepted by this journal you may need to withdraw and resubmit it elsewhere.


